# CSS overflow on apple devices only bug

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, reactjs

I've implemented a mobile version of a website http://www.ecss-jobs.com. I've used some media queries at 900px for laptop / medium devices, and 768px for phones / small devices.For Apple devices (safari and chrome), the CSS breaks for the detailed job listing page. I find this very strange as it works perfectly in the Chrome Responsive Design tool when selecting all the Apple devices...It occurs on all iPhones I believe (tested iPhone 7 and iPhone XR), though I'm unable to reproduce it on my desktop. I suspect this is because I'm using a specific CSS attribute which doesn't work for the iOS webkit but I'm only using flexbox so I'd expect this to work.

I'm not sure which parts of the CSS to attach, but the React code is not minified and available from the sources tab. The entire App overview is available at /static/js/App.tsx, and the specific module responsible for this page is at /static/js/components/JobDetails.tsx (from the sources tab). Thank you in advance.

Examples of working and not working are attached below:

Apple broken:
[image]

Android working as intended:
[image]